# Varying feature vector lengths for learning

Tags: unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection, isolation-forest, anomaly

[I am a total beginner in machine learning algorithms]
I have 10 spectrograms (lines) for phytoplankton (each composed of 288 points).
Each spectrogram is associated with a phytoplankton dendity data in the sample.
Spectrogram array dimension = 10x288
Density array dimension = 1x10
Aim: To detect an anomalous spectrum, in an unsupervised way, given the spectra and the density data? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Why do you ask about varying vector length? It seems that every instance has a fixed size: 10x288 + 1x10, right?

Comment: Thank you Erwan. Yes indeed. The way I see it is that I have 2 features (matrix of spectra + vector density), 10 instances, but I don't see how to concatenate them into one dataframe to input as X into an algorithm ? I cannot find tutorials that show how to use multivariate data of different lengths (one instance = 1 series of 288 values + one density value). Thank you

Comment: You cannot provide ML algorithms with complex "features", the data must be represented as a fixed set of numerical features. So in this case you would provide the values contained inside the matrix and the array, like concatenated all together. This is fine and potentially it could work well, but I'm more worried about the fact that you only have 10 instances apparently, this seems very low especially for unsupervised anomaly detection: the problem is that the algorithm probably won't have enough examples to find what are regular patterns vs. anomalies.

Comment: Thank you. Would you be kind enough to explaining to me how to concatenate the matrix and array into ne dataframe please? it looks likes it's a 3d matrix that's needed.

Comment: I think you have a confusion, there's no need for a dataframe really even if it's a common way to represent data nowadays. The input of a ML algorithm is always a tuple of feature values for every instance, so it's common to represent this as a matrix with features a columns and instances as rows (hence the use of a dataframe sometimes). In the case of your data, you just have make sure a specific feature is always in the same position. For example, the first row of 10 cells of the array can be the first 10 features, then the 2nd row of 10 cells can be features 11 to 20, then the 3rd row...

Comment: And the density array values can be from the 2881th to 2890th position. But as I said your issue will be number of instances probably.

Comment: Thank you Erwan, I think I understand better now.